Coupled variant of 3rd Order Newton's Method for $A\mapsto A^{-1}$?
I am interested in iteratively approximating the matrix function $A\mapsto A^{-1}$ using only matrix additions and multiplications.
One way to do this is with Newton's method, via the standard iteration (see for example Eq. 3.2).
$$\tag{1}
X_{k+1} = (2I - X_kA)X_k.
$$
In what follows, I'll let the depth of an expression (such as Eq. (1)) be the smallest depth of a circuit computing the expression, when additions are costed "for free".
For example, the expression of Eq.(1) has depth at most 2, as on input $(A, X_{k+1})$, one may

Compute $X_kA$ (depth 1), and
Compute $2I - X_kA$ (free), and
then compute $(2I-X_kA)X_k$ (depth 2).

Interestingly (at least to me), Eq.(1) may be rewritten to be depth 1 by introducing an auxiliary iteration.
In particular, one can write
\begin{align*}
W_{k+1} := X_{k+1}A &= (2I-W_k)W_k\\
X_{k+1} &= (2I-W_k)X_k.
\end{align*}
I am curious if this is also true for "higher-order" variants of Newton's method.
To make things precise, the following is the third-order variant of Newton's method
$$
X_{k+1} = (3I - 3X_kA + (X_kA)^2)X_k.\tag{2}
$$
One can try a mild modification of the same trick as before, and get
\begin{align*}
W_{k+1} := X_{k+}A &= (3I-3W_k + W_k^2)W_k\tag{3}\\
W_{k+1}^2 &= (3I-3W_k+W_k^2)^{\color{red}{2}}W_k^2\tag{4}\\
X_{k+1} &= (3I-3W_k+W_k^2)X_k\tag{5}
\end{align*}
Note here I use that $X_0, W_0$ are initialized so everything commutes, which is typical.
This almost works.
In particular, if the $\color{red}{2}$ was instead 1, the above would be a way to compute Eq. (2) in depth 1.

Can one compute Eq. (2) in depth 1?

I'm fine with using any constant (say independent of $k$) number of auxiliary iterations to do this.

This seems very similar to the way higher-order linear differential equations into vector spaces can be expressed as first-order DEs by replacing the map $y$ with the map $$\begin{bmatrix}y\y'\y''\y'''\\vdots\end{bmatrix}$$Really useful in theoretical development, but for practical calculations of no use what-so-ever, as the same calculations are being done. It just reformats them.

@PaulSinclair Yeah, that was my motivation for trying to find the depth 1 variant of Eq. (2), perhaps using multiple "parallel" iterations. I'm working in an esoteric computational paradigm where minimizing depth is more important than essentially anything else though, so this "reformatting" has the potential to be quite useful.

Why don't you use good old Gaussian elimination? When you start with an augmented matrix $[ A | I]$ and perform elementary row operations to get to $[I | A^{-1}]$ you have an iterative process that, apart from round-off errors, gets to the exact solution after a finite number of steps. Since a row operation can be recasted as a matrix multiplication, I guess this would fulfill your requirements.
